# How to Pause program inside a function until a user does something on the form

Tags: c++, qt, for-loop, events, wait

I am working on a project for my C++ Class and we are doing a poker program with AI and users. Using QT for the development.

What I need to do is inside of the function DECISION() if the player is not an AI, the program pauses until the user hits buttons to either fold, call, or Raise.

Basically I need to pause a program in the middle of executing a function, until the user presses a button. Then it will continue the rest of the function

```
if(Player[pp].ai == true){
    //A bunch of code for AI decision making for folding, calling, raising.
}
else{ //If Player is NOT an AI
    ENABLEUSERINPUT(true);

   //Need to pause program here until the user has done something to the GUI

   ENABLESERINPUT(false);

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't block, but continue to monitor events. Look into state machines

Comment: You can't structure a GUI program the way you would a command line program. You need to change your perspective from "ask the user what to do now" to "react to what the user does".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to wait for a user input using the `QEventLoop` 
for example clicking on the button will exit the event loop.

```
//Need to pause program here until the user has done something to the GUI
QEventLoop oLoop;

// user click on button will release the event loop.
connect(pYoutrBtn , &QPushButton::clicked,
        &oLoop,     &QEventLoop::quit);

// wait.
oLoop.exec();
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I've looked into QEventLoops before, but as i am still new to using QT  did not quite understand them, this helped a lot! Thanks!